# How can I keep the color when I run the external command inside vim?

Tags: shell, vim

For example, for the command `ls --color` displays colorful results when being executed in the shell. However, when I call `:!ls --color` inside vim, all color information is gone.

What should I do to keep the color when calling external command inside vim?

**EDIT: To clarify my question**, This is a question about **VIM** itself, I'm **NOT** actually asking how to enable "ls"'s  color. What I want to know is, generally how to enable the display of colorful results of *ALL* shell commands(as long as they have colorful results).

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: For people who voted to close the question, would you please leave a comment on why you doing this? I read the FAQ and this question should be about "software tools commonly used by programmers". Maybe I misunderstood something, but I don't really think this question is off topic.

Comment: "This is a question about VIM itself ..."

Comment: and vim is one of the "software tools commonly used by programmers"...

Comment: So's email. Doesn't necessarily mean "how do I Thunderbird" is on topic here.

Comment: Vim has ctags, indent and much more direct support for programming. Email does what directly for programming?

Comment: I would like to know if its possible to do it in 2021? now that we vim8.2 and neovim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CLI Vim or GUI Vim?

You can't show the output of `:!ls` or `:!ls --color` or any other external command in CLI Vim itself because it's single threaded: Vim is suspended and `$ ls --color` is executed in your shell. There's no way around that. Well, you can place the output of external commands in the current buffer but that's not the same thing.

In GUI Vim, you can only get a pseudo-shell that is totally unable to show any colors. There's no way around that either.

If you desperately need colored output from external commands you have to launch an external terminal emulator with something like `:!xterm &` *or* use a plugin like [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771).

Comment: I would suggest something like tmux or screen too.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But the asker insisted that it's a question about Vim itself. Tmux is great. Logged in on a remote server via SSH and using a well configured Vim within tmux/screen is a surprisingly enjoyable experience. Perfect for getting in the zone and staying there.

Comment: @romainl thank you for your awesome answer. I used gVim and I falsely assumed CLI vim also cannot display color... With some trials I found color is correctly displayed in my CLI vim.

Comment: Note that modern versions of gvim have `set guioptions+=!`, which makes it emulate a terminal that supports colors. I've personally seen noticeable performance issues with this, at least on boot, and other weird artifacts like an empty, uneditable buffer instead of my standard start screen (plugin; not important). There's also an open bug that blocks disowning with this option: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3327 - the point being, there's a slight workaround that makes this work, but it has other downsides. `:term` works fine though

Answer (score 1):

You can `:set shellcmdflag=-ic` to make the shell behave interactively, like your command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function in `.bashrc`:

```
function ls { /bin/ls --color=always; }
export -f ls
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but I'm not asking how to display color with "ls" command -- I'm curious about how to retain the color when executing the external commands with vim. I just used "ls" as an example.